# Window.location is being canceled in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have problem with window.location. So I have ajax request as follows:

```html
function login(){
 
 var u = document.getElementById("username").value;
 var p = document.getElementById("password").value;
 if(u == "" || p == ""){
  
 } else {
  var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "ajaxResp.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
             if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
     alert("fail");
    }
     else {
     window.location = "user.php?u="+ajax.responseText;
    }
         }
        }
        ajax.send("u="+u+"&p="+p);
 }
 return false;
}
```

where ajaxObj is decleared in other file. My ajaxResp.php send me back username to which i should redirect. But when I reach window.location, my request is cancelled. What can it mean?

Comment: And you're sure the conditions are truthy, and that you actually reach the `window.location` line at all

Comment: @adeneo, yes because I can see that request in browser inspector, and it says that it is canceled

Comment: You can see the ajax request, it's very unlikely you can see the `window.location` redirect in the console as being "canceled".

Comment: Sidenote: you have to URL-encode `ajax.responseText` in order to ensure `"user.php?u="+ajax.responseText` is valid URL

Comment: What in the world is `ajaxReturn`

Comment: Did a download start? The network tab shows cancelled when a redirect initiates a download.

Answer (score 1):

If the `window.location` line is being hit. you are not waiting for the Ajax call to be complete.

That means whatever the code is inside of the `ajaxReturn` is not checking for readyState to be complete.